# Generating function for a binary sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

I don't know this subject so my question may not be expressed in the accurate form.

Is there a function, or a structure, that generates any desired sequence of 0 and 1 of length n?
Assume we can pad the sequence if we need to, that means if the function has to adhere to a special pattern, we can make the sequence have that pattern, but still has to have the n original 0,1 sequence embedded.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What is input? What is output?

Comment: Are you referring to a function $f(i)$ that generates the $i$-th bit of the sequence, or a "generating function" function that is a polynomial whose coefficients are exactly the terms of the desired sequence? Do note that there is actually a mathematical definition of the term "generating function" : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function

Comment: Either case. The input is the sequence, the output is a function or structure that represent that sequence. I've edited the question, please let me know if it's clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but I want to say that every finite binary sequence can be represented uniquely by a natural number:

For a binary sequence $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$, form the related binary sequence $1,b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ (the $1$ is added so as to distinguish between various numbers of leading $0$s in the original sequence).  Convert this related binary sequence to a natural number via $2^n+2^{n-1}b_1+\cdots+2b_{n-1}+b_n$.

For instance $0,0,1,0,1\leftrightarrow 1,0,0,1,0,1\leftrightarrow 37$.

I think, this correspondence is unique in both directions. (I could not tell from your post which direction you wanted the correspondence to go.)

Comment: Thanks. I should have been clearer. The motivation is that the function representation uses fewer bits than the entire sequence, thus a form of compression.

Comment: Aha, That does make it more interesting!